# Permission setting for uploading only mp3 files from backend of typo3

Tags: file-upload, typo3-7.6.x

I am using typo3 7.6.11. I need to upload only mp3 files from backend through filelist module. I have created a new folder which is outside of the fileadmin directory called Medias/. Is there any setting or configuration in typo3 allowing the upload of only mp3 files other than the fileDenyPattern in the install tool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `media` extension :  https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/media/

Comment: That means we need to install this extension.